# "error setting up gummiboot-efi" on Archboot UEFI install

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, uefi

I recently purchased an Aspire XC600, but am having trouble installing Arch. I haven't installed on UEFI before. I want Arch as the only OS on the disk.

I wrote the [Archboot](https://downloads.archlinux.de/iso/archboot/2012.10) x86_64 image to a USB stick and booted from it successfully. The booting had to be done through a compatibility layer.

In the "Install Bootloader" step, I chose UEFI_x86_64, EFISTUB and GUMMIBOOT_UEFI. Gummiboot setup aborts with this error:

> error setting up gummiboot-efi

I don't think I'm in EFI mode, because:

```
# modprobe efivars
# efibootmgr
Fatal: couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.
#
```

Is the problem that I'm not in EFI mode? How can I fix that, as the USB drive can't be booted from in EFI mode? vc7 doesn't show any extra info.

Comment: You are not in UEFI mode: you can confirm that by checking for files in `/sys/firmware/efi/vars` after `modprobe efivars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're not in EFI mode then as noted already; yes, you need to get there to be able to set it up (quite cumbersome chicken-and-egg but still you can do it with UEFI-bootable media; that will not need CSM/"legacy BIOS" enabled).

I'd suggest getting through [Rod Smith's excellent pages](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) on the topic which very well might save you quite some time; not sure whether there's reason to use [gummiboot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/gummiboot.html), I prefer [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as a boot manager for a generic case (but you well might skip it since you say no need for multiboot), elilo as a bootable media starter (especially with UEFI SB and non-signed kernels), and grub 2.00 as a "common" bootloader that lets one mess with kernel boot parameters and whatnot.

Not sure regarding Arch (I've added UEFI support into ALT Linux) but have you seen the appropriate [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UEFI) [pages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UEFI_Bootloaders) then?